# Select pad around word unless start/end of string using regex

Tags: regex

I am currently extracting 5 characters of pad around a search-string with the regex command:

```
 re.findall("(.{5}searchstring.{5})",text)
```

This works fine in selecting the desired text, unless it is at the very start of the string, or the end, where there is no longer 5-characters of pad to extract.

I am looking for regex which will always extract 5-characters of text, unless the text is so close to the beginning/end of the text that there is insufficient pad - in which case to extract all it can.

For example i am looking for:

```
  `searchstring1234567`        to return   `searchstring12345',
  `12searchstring12`           to return   `12searchstring12`
  `1234567searchstring1234567` to return   `34567searchstring12345`
```

The above code works on only the 3rd of these, and returns nothing for the first two.

Comment: Do you want exactly 5 or up to 5 before and after?

Comment: `.{0,5}searchstring.{0,5}`

Comment: Thanks @luqui - that was what i wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the `{min,max}` in the range quantifier:

```
>>> re.findall("(.{0,5}searchstring.{0,5})", text)
['searchstring12345', '12searchstring12', '34567searchstring12345']
```